# Extract right Columns in Notepad++?

Tags: notepad++

I need help with Notepad++

Here I have a simple Text List:

```
Gamer453|63463462|id3256236311616
GamFlower1515|63463462|id3243362516325
```

I need only 1 Column and 3 Column

Example:

```
Gamer453|id3256236311616
```

How to extract only 1 and 3 Column in Notepad++?

Answer (score 3):

I'd use regex in search/replace.

Find: ^(.*)\|.*\|(.*)$

Replace: \1|\2

Comment: works thanks. And when i need Column 2 and 3 what i need to do?

Comment: The "\1" in the replace string is the text within the first set of parentheses in the matched string.  The ".*" in the search string can be any text, any number of characters.  The "\|" is just a literal "|".  "^" matches the beginning of a line, and "$" the end.  So the search string says "<beginning of line><any text>|<any text>|<any text><end of line>.  I put parentheses around the groups I wanted to keep for my replace string.

"^.*\|(.*)\|(.*)$" will hold the second and third columns in "\1" and "\2" respectively.

Comment: http://regex101.com/

That's a great site if you're looking to up your regex game.  Worth your time!